# Datatables jquery que me muestra campos ocultos

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Tengo en una página una tabla en la que utilizo el plugin datatables.jquery que para mi es muy práctico y funcional. 
Resulta que en la tabla uso dos campos ocultos, el id y el nrologins (este ultimo lo utilizo para ordenar los datos que trae la consulta sql)

```
<table id="tabla" class="ui celled stackable table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th hidden>nrologins</th>
                <th hidden>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

     <tbody>
            <?php
                if ($arrDatos) {
                    foreach ($arrDatos as $row) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td hidden> <?php echo $row['nrologins']; ?> </td>
                    <td hidden> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['apellido']; ?> </td>
                </tr>
            <?php }} ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Ahora bien, a pantalla completa, funciona bien pero cuando reduzco la pantalla (o por ejemplo lo veo desde el movil) los campos "ocultos" se muestran !!!... Cómo puedo hacer para evitar que eso ocurra ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta ocultar los campos en tu codigo JS, agrega lo siguiente en la configuracion de tu datatable:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 0 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        },
        {
            "targets": [ 1 ],
            "visible": false
        }
    ]
} );
```

Targets especificas la pocision de la columna que deseas ocultar.

Comment: Completamente Excelente !!!